# prevent data being loaded everytime in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have created a custom AlergDialog using DialogFragment with the help of `Android Compatibility Support Package`

In my custom dialog i have a listview inside a dialog and the content of the listview are being loaded from Sqlite Database in Android. This dialog gets popped up from a listview which is inside a fragment only.

Now t, whenever i click on listview (which is inside a fragment) a dialog appears whit the data into listview successfully , but each time i press on listitem ( which is inside a fragment) every time , the data gets load from the database in a dialog box's listview bcoz `onCreate is being called every time`  so wht i want is `data should be loaded at once for all listitem  of listview which is inside of fragment.`

**Code**

Whenever a listitem in a fragment gets clicked , i make a call to custom DialogFragment

```
DalogFragment newFragment = TemplateToContact.newInstance("hi");
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

OnCreate of DialogFragment

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        contactDB = new ContactDB(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    contactDataList = contactDB.getAllContacts();
        templateContactAdapter = new TemplateContactAdapter();

    }
```

in OnCreateDialog i create a custom alertdialog box , set the adapger and return it

```
@Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());         
   View v = factory.inflate(R.layout.cdialog, null);
   builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

   builder.setView(v);

   templateContactDlg = builder.create();                

   templateContactList = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.contactDlgList);            

   templateContactList.setAdapter(templateContactAdapter);

   return templateContactDlg;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you use DialogFragment but your code says AlertDialog. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) is an example of how to use DialogFragment. The Google Android team recommends you use DialogFragment, not AlertDialog.

added:

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            aboutFile = savedInstanceState.getString(FILE_NAME);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString(FILE_NAME, aboutFile);
    }
```

For injecting helper classes, read [this](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/SimpleExample?tm=6), for example.

Comment: I have extended the DialogFragment class and inside the class i have override the onCreateDialog menthod and from that i am masking AlertDialog box and returning it ,you can see the same in a link that you gave me , traverse to AlertDialog section

Comment: Do you use the savedInstanceState to save the data between onStop and onCreate? I usually have a data manager class between my fragment and the dao. The manager class is @Injected, and it caches the data.

Comment: I don't know how to use that , do you any sample snippet code for it

Comment: added it in my original answer because I can't format or use @ in a comment.